# How many customers bought a product A in the same order as product B

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have a table `daily_orders` where I wanted to find the Customers who bought mobile covers in the same order as mobile phone.
Here is the table structure

```
CREATE TABLE daily_orders (
  Order_date datetime,
  orderid varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  CustomerID int NOT NULL,
  Product varchar(20) ,
  Product_Category text,
  Units int
);
-- insert some values
INSERT INTO daily_orders VALUES ('2021-06-15 20:06:31','AABS123',46162,'sku1223','mobile phone',1);
INSERT INTO daily_orders VALUES ('2021-07-01 13:21:22','AABWA23',87949,'sku213','laptops',1);
INSERT INTO daily_orders VALUES ('2021-06-11 07:01:25','AA12WA13',122123,'sku1223','mobile phone',1);
INSERT INTO daily_orders VALUES ('2021-06-11 07:01:25','AA12WA13',122123,'sku1223','mobile covers',2);
```

OUTPUT should be

```
CustomerID 
122123
```

The query that I tried

```
select a.customerID
from daily_orders a
inner join daily_orders b on a.CustomerID = b.CustomerID
where a.OrderID = b.OrderID and a.CustomerID = b.CustomerID
```

But I'm not getting the desired output.
Any suggestion would be helpful.

Comment: Are you sure that you are using SQL Server?

Comment: `orderid TEXT NOT NULL` NO NO NO NO NO! This datatype has been deprecated for 20 years. Get help designing tables and databases. That is a skill that must be learned and does not magically come with some level of SQL knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join the table with itself (one instance for covers, the other one for phones) to get the result you want. For example:

```
select c.CustomerId
from daily_orders c
join daily_orders p on p.orderid = c.orderid
where c.Product_Category = 'mobile covers'
  and p.Product_Category = 'mobile phone'
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a "does something exist" query, best fulfilled using *exists*.

Also note that *Text* data types have long been deprecated and should no longer be used, always specify *varchar(n)*.

```
select o.CustomerID 
from daily_orders o
where Product_Category = 'mobile phone'
and exists (
  select * from daily_orders o2 
    where o2.orderid = o.orderid 
      and o2.Product_Category = 'mobile covers'
);
```

Answer (score 1):

another option is to use string_agg

```
select t.customerid
from   ( select d.customerid,
                string_agg(convert(varchar(100), d.Product_Category), ',') cat
         from   daily_orders d
         group by d.customerid
       ) t  
where  t.cat = 'mobile phone,mobile covers'
```

[DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7c9325c61419c55485c2f06490d6b8a9) here

Comment: But [don't convert to `varchar` without specifying a length](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length).

Comment: @AaronBertrand You are right, I edited my answer

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the data type of `orderid` and `Product_Category` is `VARCHAR` and not `TEXT` and there is no case of different `CustomerID`s for each `orderid`, first filter the table to get only customers who bought 'mobile covers' and/or 'mobile phone' and then use aggregation to get only the customers who bought both in the same order:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CustomerID 
FROM daily_orders 
WHERE Product_Category IN ('mobile covers', 'mobile phone')
GROUP BY CustomerID, orderid 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Product_Category) = 2;
```

Or with [`INTERSECT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-except-and-intersect-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

```
SELECT DISTINCT CustomerID
FROM (
  SELECT CustomerID, orderid FROM daily_orders WHERE Product_Category = 'mobile covers'
  INTERSECT
  SELECT CustomerID, orderid FROM daily_orders WHERE Product_Category = 'mobile phone'
) t
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=6be057e9e4dba079d00f72c8ec5ace92).

Answer (score 0):

The below query should work if you change the datatype from text to varchar

> Table Definition

```
CREATE TABLE daily_orders (
  Order_date datetime,
  orderid varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  CustomerID int NOT NULL,
  Product varchar(20),
  Product_Category varchar(20),
  Units int
);
```

> Solution

```
SELECT dor1.customerid,
       dor1.product_category,
       dor2.product_category
FROM   daily_orders dor1
       inner join daily_orders dor2
               ON dor1.customerid = dor2.customerid
                  AND dor1.orderid = dor2.orderid
WHERE  dor1.product_category <> dor2.product_category
       AND dor1.product_category = 'mobile phone'
       AND dor2.product_category = 'mobile covers';
```